# IWebClient injecting a webclient interface as a dependency

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that calls a web service. I want to mock webclient but cant find any interface on webclient.

What is the best practice here? Ultimately i want to use moq and setup the downloadstring method on webclient to be static value in my tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a wrapper around `WebClient`. The ASP.NET team was forced to do the same thing with `HttpContextBase/Wrapper` to enable easy testing with ASP.NET MVC.